# Handling sparse document term matrix

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, sparse

I am working with a corpus of several thousand documents (41,732) however the documents tend to be short (the median number of terms per document is 3) resulting in a sparse document term matrix.

Does the number of documents or the length of the documents have a greater contribution to sparsity in a document term matrix?

When sparsity is high, are there analytical approaches for finding "insights"?

Comment: I think that this problem is addressed by _sparse topic models_. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh thanks. I've never heard of them but will look them up

Comment: You're welcome. Here are some papers that might be of your interest: [this](https://dslpitt.org/uai/papers/11/p831-zhu.pdf), [this](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~bao/papers/ECML2012.pdf), [this](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4784-factorial-lda-sparse-multi-dimensional-text-models.pdf), [this](http://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/papers/mimno2012sparse.pdf), [this](http://bigml.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/~jun/pub/online-stc.pdf), [this](http://www.ecmlpkdd2013.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/280.pdf), [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chongw/papers/WangBlei2009b.pdf). To be cont'd.

Comment: (Cont'd) Papers: [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.4510v2.pdf), [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10715/project-reports/WangLiLin.pdf). Not sure how relevant [this paper](http://bcmi.sjtu.edu.cn/~zhangliqing/Papers/2012NeuroComp-ZhuWenjun.pdf), but I'm sure you will figure it out. You might also want to check SAGE models - see [this discussion](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86700/31372) for details.